# Kernel and Image of Homomorphism, Modulo 15

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $6·81^k ≡ 6 \enspace \pmod{15}$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Use this to prove that $\operatorname{Ker}\left( \phi\right) = 4\mathbb{Z}$, while $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ is the cyclic subgroup of $G_{15}$ generated by $[13]$.
>
> (The function $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to G_{15}$ is given by: $\phi(x) = 10+6·3^x \enspace \pmod{15}$)

I can prove the first part fairly easily. I'm struggling to prove the statements about the kernel and image of $\phi$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the definition of a kernel and that $3^{4k}=81^k$.

Comment: How is $3^{-1}$ defined? $3$ is not unit mod. $15$.